# Dynamically generated page URLs don't work this morning

Tags: facebook, hyperlink

This morning dynamically generated links to FB pages from our app stopped working. Link to a page like this http://www.facebook.com/pages/125567350861413 used to work just fine, now it requires page name http://www.facebook.com/pages/Daniels-Real-Estate/125567350861413

**Why would this be changed? Was there a problem with old pages link format?**

We tweaked our code to take into account page name and made it work. But if a user changes the name of a page the link to this page will break, until we refresh the list of pages in our db. We'll write a chron job that will refresh the list of page names for all users using our app multiple times a day, but we'd prefer not having to do that.

Anyone else ran into this issue? What was your workaround (other than the above)?

Comment: When you post links to real live pages it makes me wonder if it's spam or not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is probably an off-topic question, you can get the page url using the graph api:
http://graph.facebook.com/125567350861413 and looking at the `link` property.  As to why Facebook changed this, you would have to ask them at their [developer group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/) or [log a bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs).

Comment: Hmm, we'll check that out. Thanks!